# Help in shortening a sentence

Tags: verbs

The original sentence is

> Default minimum placing amount is 1 credit, and maximum placing
>   credits amount is none, the game creators can adjust which to a
>   positive integer.

The sentence is used to describe some parameters when a website member creates a betting game for other players to participate in.

Can I shorten the sentence to

> Default minimum and maximum placing amount **are** 1 credit and none,
>   the creators can adjust which to a positive integer.

And if yes, should I use “is” or “are”?

Thanks in advance for your worthy knowledge.

Comment: I think you should specify if the word "default" applies to both "minimum placing amount" and "maximum placing credits amount" or it just indicates the default amount of the "minimum placing amount"? And also, are "placing amount" and "placing credits amount" the same? If so, you can shorten the sentence like this: *Default minimum and maximum placing credits amounts are 1 and none, respectively ...* If they are not the same, I thinks it will be like this: *Default minimum placing amount and maximum placing credits amount are 1 and none, respectively ...*

Answer (score 1):

In the example you use, it is usually better to state the amounts

> **The** default minimum and maximum placing amount**s** are **1** and **0** credit**s** *(respectively)*, **which** the creators can adjust *(to a positive integer)*.